# I want to combine three txt-files into one single file in c#

Tags: c#, text

Im new to C# but learning as I go forward, so forgive me if my question might be a little too easy for most of you guys. :-)

My question has two parts.

- First:  I have three textfiles (with fixed names) with totaly
  different contents. I now want these combine into one single
  textfile.
- Second:  During this combination process I also want every comma(,)
  in these files to be changed to a dot(.) in the output combined file.

I have managed to do something similar with StreamReader and StreamWriter in combination with ReadLine in vb but cant get it to work in C#.

Im thankful for any help I can get.

/Tomas

Comment: read the 3 files to string (google it, its not hard) do a `.Replace` for your `,` `.` and just `+` them to each other

Answer (score 4):

If files are not big you can use this snippet:

```
File.WriteAllText("newfile", String.Concat(File.ReadAllText("file1"),File.ReadAllText("file2"),File.ReadAllText("file3")).Replace(",","."));
```

Answer (score 2):

In *general case* when files are *long* with *arbitrary* number of files you can try *Linq* `SelectMany`:

```
 using System.IO; 
 using System.Linq; 

 ...

 string[] fileNames = new string[] {
   @"C:\MyFile1.txt", 
   @"C:\MyFile2.txt",
   @"C:\MyFile3.txt", 
 };

 ...

 File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\MyCombinedFile.txt", fileNames
   .SelectMany(file => File.ReadLines(file))
   .Select(line => line.Replace(',', '.')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] files = new string[]{ @"E:\myfile1.txt", @"E:\myfile2.txt", @"E:\myfile3.txt" };

        string fileContent = string.Empty;
        foreach (var fileName in files)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader Reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                fileContent += Reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        fileContent = fileContent.Replace(',', '.');

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"E:\myfile.txt", fileContent);
```

Comment: Thank you guys. Problem solved. You rock! :-)